# Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

Create the Web Service Client Project using jax-ws it gives me following error
Create project using Netbeans 7.2,JSK 1.6,Apache Tomcat 7

what is the error for.. Missing some jar files

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:445)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:342)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:157)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:260)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:223)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:171)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:96)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
at org.example.centralizewebservices.schema.CentralizeWebService.<init>(CentralizeWebService.java:42)
at services.servicesImpl.HomeServicesImpl.<init>(HomeServicesImpl.java:46)
at dwr.DwrCommand.getEventListForCalenderByDate(DwrCommand.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule$1.doFilter(CreatorModule.java:229)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule.executeMethod(CreatorModule.java:241)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:379)
at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:332)
at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:104)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120)
at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:141)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Looks like a classloading error. Tomcat screwed with the classloading mechanism between TC 6-7. See if http://azagozdzinski.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/saaj-problem/ helps