# jacoco:cover from play console gives NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID

Tags: scala, sbt, jacoco

Running `jacoco:cover` from the Play console using `jacoco4sbt` (2.1.4) results in many tests failing and messages like:

> [debug] Running
>   TaskDef(com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec,
>   org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$1@5b98f69a, false,
>   [SuiteSelector])
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:445)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:342)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:157)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:257)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:220)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.(WSServiceDelegate.java:168)
>         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:96)
>         at javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:77)
>         at com.bsl.Services.(Services.java:46)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.UserRepositoryComponent$OdsUserRepository.(UserRepositoryComponent.scala:92)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.ComponentRegistry$class.$init$(ComponentRegistry.scala:7)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec$TestLoginController$.(LoginControllerSpec.scala:20)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec.TestLoginController$lzycompute(LoginControllerSpec.scala:20)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec.TestLoginController(LoginControllerSpec.scala:20)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(LoginControllerSpec.scala:32)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(LoginControllerSpec.scala:32)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(LoginControllerSpec.scala:32)
>         at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
>         at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
>         at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
>         at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
>         at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
>         at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1636)
>         at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1121)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1633)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1645)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1645)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1645)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1703)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1703)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
>         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:390)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:427)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
>         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1703)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
>         at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1423)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1749)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1749)
>         at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
>         at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1749)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(LoginControllerSpec.scala:11)
>         at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:257)
>         at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:256)
>         at com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec.run(LoginControllerSpec.scala:11)
>         at org.scalatest.tools.Framework.org$scalatest$tools$Framework$$runSuite(Framework.scala:444)
>         at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:651)
>         at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:84)
>         at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:94)
>         at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
>         at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
>         at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:212)
>         at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
>         at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:224)
>         at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:229)
>         at sbt.Tests$.sbt$Tests$$processRunnable$1(Tests.scala:211)
>         at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
>         at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$makeSerial$1.apply(Tests.scala:217)
>         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
>         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
>         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
>         at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>         at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>         at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
>         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
>         at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>         at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
>         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>       [error] Could not run test com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.LoginControllerSpec:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.BindingID

**LoginControlerSpec**

```
package com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity

import org.scalatest.{ Matchers, BeforeAndAfterAll, FlatSpec }
import play.api.test.{ FakeApplication, FakeRequest }
import com.ourCompany.ourProject.tags.UnitTest
import play.api.Play
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import play.api.test.Helpers._

@UnitTest
class LoginControllerSpec extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with Mockito with Matchers {
  override def beforeAll() {
    Play.start(FakeApplication())
  }

  override def afterAll() {
    Play.stop()
  }

  object TestLoginController extends LoginController with Secured with ComponentRegistryMock

  val Home = "/"
  val username = "XXX@ourCompanyprofessional.com"
  val password = "XXX1"
  val isRememberMe = false
  val expirationPolicy = SessionExpirationPolicy
  val odsUser = OdsUser(Identity(username, ""), Some(username))

  behavior of "LoginController"

  it should "send 200 for renderLoginForm with not authenticated user" in {
    status(TestLoginController.renderLoginForm(FakeRequest())) should be(OK)
  }

  it should "send 303 for renderLoginForm with authenticated user" in {
    val cookie = TestLoginController.authenticatorService.create(odsUser.identity, expirationPolicy) match {
      case Right(a: Authenticator) => a.toCookie
      case _ => fail()
    }
    TestLoginController.userRepository.find(odsUser.identity.userId) returns Some(odsUser)
    val result = TestLoginController.renderLoginForm(FakeRequest().withCookies(cookie))
    redirectLocation(result) should be(Some(Home))
    status(result) should be(SEE_OTHER)
  }

  it should "send 303 for login with valid credentials" in {
    val fakeRequest = FakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(
      UsernameField -> username, PasswordField -> password, RememberMeField -> isRememberMe.toString)

    TestLoginController.userRepository.login(username, password) returns Right(odsUser)
    val result = TestLoginController.login(fakeRequest)
    cookies(result).get(Authenticator.cookieName) match {
      case Some(c) => assert(c.name == Authenticator.cookieName && !c.value.isEmpty)
      case _ => fail()
    }
    redirectLocation(result) should be(Some(Home))
    status(result) should be(SEE_OTHER)
  }

  it should "send 400 for login with invalid credentials" in {
    val fakeRequest = FakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(
      UsernameField -> username, PasswordField -> password, RememberMeField -> isRememberMe.toString)

    TestLoginController.userRepository.login(username, password) returns Left(new Error)
    val result = TestLoginController.login(fakeRequest)
    status(result) should be(BAD_REQUEST)
  }

  it should "send 400 for login with invalid form input" in {
    val fakeRequest = FakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(
      UsernameField -> "", PasswordField -> "", RememberMeField -> "")

    val result = TestLoginController.login(fakeRequest)
    status(result) should be(BAD_REQUEST)
  }

}
```

**build.sbt**

```
gitHeadCommitSha in ThisBuild := Process("git rev-parse HEAD").lines.head

(testOptions in Test) += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/report")

org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.Settings

scalacOptions := Seq("-feature")
```

**build.scala**

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform._
import play.Project._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._
import sbtbuildinfo.Plugin._
import scala._
import scala.util.Try
import scala.Some
import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin._

object BuildSettings {
  val buildOrganization = "com.ourCompany.ourProject"
  val buildVersion      = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.10.2"
  val envConfig = "-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsbt.log.format=false -Dconfig.file=" + 
      Option(System.getProperty("env.config")).getOrElse("local.application")
  val maxErrors = 20
  // disable running browserstack tests by default. Possible options: true | false [default]
  val browserstack: Boolean = Try(System.getProperty("test.browserstack").toBoolean).getOrElse(false)

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    organization := buildOrganization,
    version      := buildVersion,
    scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion,
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-optimise", "-deprecation",
      "-Xcheckinit", "-encoding", "utf8", "-feature", "-Yinline-warnings",
      "-Xfatal-warnings"),
    javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M","-Xmx1536M", "-Xss1M", "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=192M",
      "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled", "-XX:MaxPermSize=512M"),
    javaOptions += envConfig,
    publishMavenStyle := false
  )
}

object Resolvers {
  val remoteRepoUrl = "ourCompany Nexus Snapshots" at "http://nexus.ci.bln.ourCompany-xxx.com/content/repositories/snapshots/"
  val publishRepoUrl = "ourCompany Nexus Snapshots" at "http://nexus.ci.bln.ourCompany-xxx.com/content/repositories/snapshots/"
  val releaseRepoUrl = "ourCompany Nexus Releases" at "http://nexus.ci.bln.ourCompany-xxx.com/content/repositories/releases/"
}

object Dependencies {
  val ods =  "de.bsmo.ourCompany-professional" % "sprprof-ws" % "2.2.1-SNAPSHOT"
  val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0" % "test->*"  withSources()
  val mockito = "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "test"
  val ghostDriver = "com.github.detro.ghostdriver" % "phantomjsdriver" % "1.0.3" % "test"
  val cmsClient = "com.ourCompany.cms.ws.clients" % "ourCompany-cms-java-api" % "1.1.6"
  val solrjClient = "org.apache.solr" % "solr-solrj" % "4.3.1" % "compile"
}

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  import BuildSettings._
  import Dependencies._
  import Resolvers._

  // Sub-project specific dependencies
  val commonDeps = Seq(
    ods,
    scalatest,
    mockito,
    ghostDriver,
    cmsClient,
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    filters,
    solrjClient,
    cache
  )
  //val bN = settingKey[Int]("current build Number")
  val gitHeadCommitSha = settingKey[String]("current git commit SHA")
  val release = settingKey[Boolean]("Release")

  lazy val ourProject = play.Project(
    "ourProject",
    path = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ buildSettings ++
      Seq(libraryDependencies ++= commonDeps) ++
      Seq(scalariformSettings: _*) ++
      Seq(playScalaSettings: _*) ++
      Seq(publishArtifact := false) ++
      buildInfoSettings ++
      jacoco.settings ++
      Seq(
        sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo,
        buildInfoKeys ++= Seq[BuildInfoKey](
          resolvers,
          libraryDependencies in Test,
          buildInfoBuildNumber,
          BuildInfoKey.map(name) { case (k, v) => "project" + k.capitalize -> v.capitalize },
          "envConfig" -> envConfig, // computed at project load time
          BuildInfoKey.action("buildTime") {
            System.currentTimeMillis
          } // re-computed each time at compile
        ),
        buildInfoPackage := "com.ourCompany.ourProject"
      ) ++
      Seq(resolvers += remoteRepoUrl) ++
      Seq(resolvers += releaseRepoUrl) ++
      Seq(mappings in Universal ++= Seq(
        file("ops/rpm/start-server.sh") -> "start-server.sh",
        file("ops/rpm/stop-server.sh") -> "stop-server.sh"
      )) ++
      Seq(testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(if(browserstack) "-n" else "-l", "com.ourCompany.ourProject.tags.BrowserStackTest"))
  ).settings(version <<=  version in ThisBuild)
  .settings(parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false)
  .settings({
    if(browserstack) {
      javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/browserstack.application.conf"
    } else {
      javaOptions in Test += "-Dtest.none=true"
    }
  })



  lazy val ourProjectPackaging = Project(
    "packaging",
    file("ourProjectPackaging"), settings=
      Defaults.defaultSettings ++
      Seq(Packaging.settings:_*) ++
      Seq(resolvers += publishRepoUrl) ++
      buildSettings ++
      publishSetting ++
      Seq(publishArtifact := false) ++
      credentialsSetting
  ).settings(Packaging.rpmDistSettings: _*).settings(version <<=  version in Rpm )

  lazy val credentialsSetting = credentials += {
    Seq("NEXUS_USER", "NEXUS_PASSWORD").map(k => Option(System.getenv(k))) match {
      case Seq(Some(user), Some(pass)) =>
        Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager",
          "nexus.ci.bln.ourCompany-xxx.com", user, pass)
      case _ =>
        Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
    }
  }

  lazy val publishSetting = publishTo <<= version.apply{
    v =>
      val nexus = "http://nexus.ci.bln.ourCompany-xxx.com/"
      if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
        Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
      else
        Some("releases" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
  }
}
```

**Sequenze of commands**

1. Starting Play Console (play)
2. clean
3. jacoco:cover

**Details**

Version of Play: play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_45)
Play about:

```
[info] This is sbt 0.13.0
[info] The current project is {file:/home/schl14/work/ProjektName/}ProjektName 0.1-b012d0e6a2c5b4a746490c0d34856af5e7d09bb9
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.2
[info] Available Plugins: play.Project, com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin, org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtScalariform, sbtbuildinfo.Plugin, org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin, de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.2
```

**Question**

It worked previously (as in many many commits ago) and I failed to pinpoint what changes to the sourcecode made `jacoco:cover` fail. What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Once solved i will cut down on the amount of unecesary info posted here! Currently its hard to determin what needs to be provided.

Comment: Could you share the entire stack trace? How does the `LoginControllerSpec` look like? What's the version of Play? What is the sequence of sbt/play command to get at that error? What's `build.sbt` and/or `project/*.scala` files? It looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/14118341/1305344.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski added info as requested. Yes the error looks like the link you provided but iam unable to bring the proposed solution into my context. Would you please go into detail how to solve it in a jacoco scenario?

Comment: Are you using JDK or JRE? Could you run `play about` within the project? I'd also look at `com.ourCompany.ourProject.identity.UserRepositoryComponent$OdsUserRepository.(UserRepositoryComponent.scala:92)` as it calls `com.bsl.Services.(Services.java:46)` that has a dependency on an external WSDL file. Could it be that the WSDL is not available or has issues that in turn cause the errors in the project? Guessing...

Comment: Added the play about output. JDK is instaled (jdk-7u45-linux-x64). If there would be a problem with the WSDL i would expect it to be an issue when compiling or testing the code regulary (without jacoco) an issue too. Will look at it still. Guesses? :)

Comment: Not that it may help much, but `javaOptions += envConfig` is incorrect - `inspect javaOptions` shows it's of `Seq[java.lang.String]` type so `envConfig` should become a Seq and use `++=` to add the new values. Add is the case for `javaOptions` a line above.

Comment: Also `build.sbt` looks suspiciously old (as if it was written for the older versions of SBT). I'd recommend rewriting it to use `:=`, `+=` and `++=` operators with `.value` inside when dependency between tasks is needed. It will greatly simplify narrowing down the issue.
Is the stacktrace of `jacoco:cover` complete? Could you execute `debug` before it? I believe there's more in the stacktrace.